# linking error for mergesort() from the C standard library

Tags: c, linux, makefile

This is my source file but when I compile it i got undefined reference to mergesort.

```
#include <lcthw/darray_algos.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int DArray_qsort(DArray * array,DArray_compare cmp)
    {
    qsort(array->contents,   DArray_count(array), sizeof(void *), cmp);
    return 0;
    }

    int DArray_heapsort(DArray * array, DArray_compare cmp)
    {
    return heapsort(array->contents, DArray_count(array),
            sizeof(void *), cmp);
    }

    int DArray_mergesort(DArray * array, DArray_compare cmp)
    {
    return mergesort(array->contents, DArray_count(array),
            sizeof(void *), cmp);
    }
```

I dont know how to link the stdlib sorting functions correctly I been using this generic makefile but it seems to failing the stdlib

```
   CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc    -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
LDFLAGS=$(OPTLIBS)
PREFIX?=/usr/local

SOURCES=$(wildcard src/**/*.c src/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

TEST_SRC=$(wildcard tests/*_tests.c)
TESTS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(TEST_SRC))

TARGET=build/liblcthw.a

OS=$(shell lsb_release -si)
ifeq ($(OS),Ubuntu)
    LDLIBS=-llcthw -lbsd -L./build -lm
endif

# The Target Build
all: $(TARGET) tests

dev: CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Isrc -Wall -Wextra $(OPTFLAGS)
dev: all

$(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $(OBJECTS)
    ranlib $@

build:
    @mkdir -p build
    @mkdir -p bin
```

Comment: Where are `heapsort` and `mergesort` defined?

Comment: `mergesort() from the C standard library` - there is no mergesort() in C standard library.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else going through the Learn C The Hard Way book by Zed A. Shaw, in the makefile you can also replace this block:

```
OS=$(shell lsb_release -si)
ifeq ($(OS),Ubuntu)
    LDLIBS=-llcthw -lbsd -L./build -lm
endif
```

With the following:

```
OS=$(shell uname -a)
ifeq (Linux,$(findstring Linux,$(OS)))
    LDLIBS=-llcthw -lbsd -L./build -lm
endif
```

Which should work with any Linux distro without disrupting the makefile execution on a Mac. The reason this is happening is stdlib.h in Linux has an implementation of quick sort but not of heap sort and merge sort so the BSD stdlib.h (which is what Mr. Shaw is using on his Mac) should be used instead.

In darray_algos.c you may also need to replace:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

with:

```
#include <bsd/stdlib.h>
```

to get rid of warnings when compiling.

Answer (score 1):

`heapsort` and `mergesort` are not part of the standard library in C. You should look at a C++ compiler to have these functions.

Comment: Why? You won't find them in C++ (well, there is a heap sort but that algorithm has a different name...). They're from *BSD libcs.

Answer (score 1):

`mergesort() from the C standard library` - there is no mergesort() in C standard library. The function does not come from [the C standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header).

I have found [man mergesort](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mergesort) on linux.die.net, which suggest the function is from BSD systems. So you should link your program against `-lbsd`.

In your makefile you have:

```
OS=$(shell lsb_release -si)
ifeq ($(OS),Ubuntu)
    LDLIBS=-llcthw -lbsd -L./build -lm
endif
```

It should be done for all linux hosts that have bsd package installed. Remove that check.